# How can I stop the Visual Studio debug window appearing when a process crashes?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, process

I have a server that runs processes that are playing up. We have a third-party process monitoring service running that will detect when a process dies.

However, the server also has VS 2005 installed. When the process fails, it displays the 'Choose Debugger' and doesn't actually quit. Our process monitoring doesn't detect a missing process and nobody is any wiser.

How can I stop the VS 'do you want to debug?' window popping up and just let the process error/quit?

Thanks in advance for any help

Ryan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[this](http://mahiways.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!6A1F270FEA8CDD8C!362.entry) link might help you and may i ask why do you have vs installed on a server?

Comment: Yup - thank you!
Here is the official MS piece: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8kf6y2a%28VS.80%29.aspx
As for VS on the Server, I don't know. I am going to ask around and try to remove it (it doesn't really make sense)